# Ionic 2 Tabs Not setting to root

Tags: angular, typescript, tabs, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

Hi There Im working on Ionic 2 beta 11. But It seems like there have lots of bugs..

Im having problem with Ionic 2 tabs. 
The problem is Tabs are not setting to root..
Means When app is open I pressed on any tab and again some other tab..
and then pressed back button Its not closing the app but it navigates to previous tab/page.

My Code:

app.ts

```
import {Component,Inject, ViewChild,enableProdMode} from "@angular/core";
import {Platform, ionicBootstrap,MenuController, NavController,Keyboard}from 'ionic-angular';`
import {StatusBar, Splashscreen} from 'ionic-native';
import {TabsPage} from './pages/tabs/tabs';
import {SigninPage} from './pages/signin/signin';
import {disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms} from '@angular/forms';
import {EventDetailsPage} from './pages/event-details/event-details'; 
import {AuthService} from "./pages/signin/authservice";
import {myEvents} from "./pages/myEvents/myEvents";
import {Page1} from './pages/page1/page1';
// import {enableProdMode} from 'angular2/core';
 import {Geolocation} from 'ionic-native';`

 declare var navigator:any;
 declare var cordova:any;
 enableProdMode();`

@Component({
 templateUrl: 'build/app.html',
providers: [AuthService]
})

export class MyApp {
rootPage: any;
userEvents: any = myEvents;
 // static companyLogin:boolean;
@ViewChild('content') nav: NavController;
 public local = null;
 constructor(platform: Platform, public menu: MenuController,      keyboard: Keyboard) {

platform.ready().then(() => {
  console.log('platform works..');
  Splashscreen.hide();
  StatusBar.styleDefault();

  // cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
  // cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(false);
  // cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

// keyboard.disableScroll(true)

  let local =  window.localStorage.getItem('ecnob.token');
  let getType = window.localStorage.getItem('type');
   if(local == null){
    this.rootPage = SigninPage;
    //  console.log("app ts root Nav");
    this.menu.enable(false);
  }
  else{
  //   if(getType == 1){
  //     console.log('type value',getType);
  //     MyApp.companyLogin = true;
  //    }
  //  else{
  //     MyApp.companyLogin = false;
  //      console.log('type value',getType);
  //     }
      this.menu.enable(true);
      this.rootPage  = TabsPage;
  //  console.log('company login',MyApp.companyLogin);
  }


}

)}

//================ MY Events Screen =============//`

goEvents(){

  this.nav.push(myEvents);
}

//================ MY Events Screen  END  =============//




 //======================== LOG OUT FUNCTION ===================///
logout(){
 AuthService.logout().then((succ)=>{

  console.log('loogin out');

  this.menu.enable(false);
  this.nav.setRoot(SigninPage);

 },(err)=>{
   console.log('getting error',err);
  //  window.alert('Something went wrong.. Please try again');
 })




}
}
//============================== END ===============================//


ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [
disableDeprecatedForms(),
provideForms()
],{tabsPlacement: "bottom",tabsHideOnSubPages: true,
  tabsHighlight: true})
```

app.html:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
<ion-content>
<!-- Some side menu contents -->
</ion-content>
<ion-nav id="nav" #content [root]="rootPage" swipeBackEnabled="false">      </ion-nav>`
```

tabs HTML:

```
<ion-tabs  class="foo-tabs"  #myTabs primary>
<ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" (ionSelect)="select(0)"   tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
 <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Deals" (ionSelect)="select(1)" tabIcon="pricetags"  ></ion-tab>
 <ion-tab [root]="tab3Allevent" tabTitle="Events" (ionSelect)="select(2)" tabIcon="calendar"></ion-tab>
 <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="Companies" (ionSelect)="select(3)" tabIcon="grid"></ion-tab>
 </ion-tabs>`
```

tabs ts:

```
import {Component,ViewChild} from "@angular/core";
import {Page1} from '../page1/page1';
import {CreateDealPage} from '../create-deal/create-deal';
import {Page3} from '../page3/page3';
import {AllCompaniesPage} from '../all-companies/all-companies';
import {AllEventsPage} from '../all-events/all-events';
import {DealsPage} from '../deals/deals';
import {EventDetailsPage} from '../event-details/event-details'; 
import {NavController,NavParams,MenuController,Tabs} from 'ionic-angular';
import {DataService} from '../../service/dataService/dataService';
// import {SigninPage} from '../signin/signin';
@Component({
 templateUrl: 'build/pages/tabs/tabs.html'
 })
 export class TabsPage {
 private param;
 // this tells the tabs component which Pages
 // should be each tab's root Page
 @ViewChild('myTabs') myTabs: Tabs;
 ionViewDidEnter() {
 // window.alert('view enter');
  var t: Tabs = this.nav.parent;
 t.select(this.param);
 //  this.nav.getActive();
 // console.log('privous tab',this.myTabs);
 // this.nav.parent.select(tabIndex); 
  }
 select(param){
 console.log('param select',param);
 this.param = param;
 //  var t: Tabs = this.nav.parent;
 //  t.select(0);
}
 private tab1Root: any;
 private tab2Root: any; //deals Page
 private tab3Allevent: any;
 private tab4Root: any ; 
 constructor(public nav:NavController){
 this.tab1Root = Page1;
 this.tab2Root = DealsPage;
 this.tab3Allevent = AllEventsPage;
 this.tab4Root = AllCompaniesPage
 }
 }
```

Dont Know.. What gets next

Comment: [Here is a solution I proposed regarding that matter.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539573/ionic-2-cancel-hard-back-button-override-to-close-app-on-back-button-when-use)