# Ionic 2 cancel hard BACK button override -> To close app on back button when user is on one of the main Tab pages

Tags: ionic2

I want to have the android **back button to close the app** if the user is on one of the two **main pages**. Both pages can be navigated to with two tabs button, which are shown on those both pages. But **on any other pages I want to keep normal stack pages behaviour**.

I read about [registerBackButtonAction](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/#registerBackButtonAction) and also got some information in this [thread concerning Ionic 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231737/ionic-override-all-back-button-behaviour-for-specific-controller).

I created a custom behaviour to close the app:

```
private registerSpecificActionOnBackButton = () => {
  if(this.platform.is('android')||this.platform.is('windows')){
    this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(function(e){
      this.platform.exitApp();
    }.bind(this),101);
  }
}
```

My idea is to call the `registerSpecificActionOnBackButton()` function in the `ionViewWillEnter()` function on the pages where this behaviour is needed.

But **I don't manage to cancel that behaviour on the `ionViewWillLeave()`** function with a `deRegisterSpecificActionOnBackButton()` function, I've tried among other things:

```
private deRegisterSpecificActionOnBackButton = () => {
  if(this.platform.is('android')||this.platform.is('windows')){
    this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(function(e){return true},101);
  }
}
```

Or

```
private deRegisterSpecificActionOnBackButton = () => {
  if(this.platform.is('android')||this.platform.is('windows')){
    this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(function(event){event.unbind()},101);
  }
}
```

But I happen to be stuck. Has anyone any idea about **canceling a custom registerBackButtonAction**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to make this work as I expect: **When the app is on one of the pages that can be reached thru the tabs menu, it closes when the back button is hitten (on Android).**

First, forget about the `registerBackButtonAction()` for the moment because as quoting what is explained in [this thread of 2016-08-05](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/registerbackbuttonaction-default-action/59445):

> *it* suggest*s* not trying to override the default back button behavior.

So I've looked for other solutions. I've found one that is not really clean but works.

To begin with, I looked if I could reset the stack with the `NavControler` using `remove(startIndex, removeCount, opts)`. But that doesn't work out because the two main pages are embeded in the tab page (like it is shown [there](https://blog.khophi.co/ionic-2-side-menu-tabs/)).

So when you're on one of those pages the `NavController` is a `Tab` and the `parent` of that is a `Tabs`.

In `Tabs` there is a Array variable named `_selectHistory`. The `_selectHistory` array seems to have a role similar to the stack. So when navigating from one page to another using the two tab buttons, one can see in a `console.info(this.[NavControler var of the page].parent._selectHistory)` that the array grows as the tab buttons are hitten alternatively. And when trying on a real device, the back button take you back switching from one page to another until the array is empty and then the next back button hit closes the app.

Hence I thought: Let see what happens if I override the value of that array. It cannot be done thru a function to apply on a `Tabs` object (unlike what is possible with `NavController`).

So in the Page concerning my pages embedded in the Tab page, I added the following in   ionViewWillEnter():

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
   this.navCtrl.parent._selectHistory=[];
}
```

`This.navCtrl` is my NavController object passed in the constructor of the page.

That's it.