# Ionic 2 - Prevent exit app on hardware back button

Tags: ionic2, default, exit, back-button

In my Ionic 2 App the hardware back button (android, windows) should work like he is doing it on default, with one exception: He should not exit the app if there is nothing to go back.

I know I can do it like this:

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
    platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
        // Default action with the exception here
    },);
});
```

But how must I do it exactly now, to make it work as default but with this one exception? In the [ionic 1 docs of that function](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/service/$ionicPlatform/#registerBackButtonAction) there are the priorities of the different cases. But I think that got changed in ionic 2!? Because in the [ionic 2 docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#registerBackButtonAction) there are not these priorities. I have tried to set the priority to 99, because then everything should work as default. But now the sidemenu can not be closed anymore and thats why I think the priorities of ionic 1 have been changed, because in the ionic 1 docs the priority of the sidemenu is 150 and thats why my function should be ignored. Someone can help me with it?

Comment: related to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539573/ionic-2-cancel-hard-back-button-override-to-close-app-on-back-button-when-use

Answer (score 11):

```
constructor(public nav: NavController, private platform: Platform, public menu: MenuController) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {
          // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
          // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need

          platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
            if(this.menu.isOpen()){
               this.menu.close()
            } 
            else if(this.nav.canGoBack()){
              this.nav.pop();
            }else{
              //don't do anything
            }
          });
        });

      }
```

Comment: No thats not the default operation... The sidemenu for example does not close anymore with your code.

Comment: for that case, I have edited the code. Please check that if it fits your case

Answer (score 4):

Just set the property `navExitApp` to `false` in file `app.module.ts` at imports

```
IonicModule.forRoot(YourApp, {
  navExitApp: false
}),
```

Easy! :)

Comment: +1 This is a quick-win solution if all you want is to prevent the back button from exiting the app. The `registerBackButtonAction` method seems to override all default actions (e.g. closing side menu etc) so we need to implement all those logic again; too much trouble >___<